# Codeigniter LEFT JOIN not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

My left join is not working. I would like anything from messages to output but if nothing from replies just have it blank.

I have tried straight mySQL (see below), original using the codeigniter query builder.

I have verified all SQL fields.

```
$this->db->select('messages.*, replies.*');
$this->db->from('messages');
$this->db->join('replies', 'replies.messageID = messages.id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get();

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT       messages.*, replies.*
                        FROM        messages
                        LEFT JOIN   replies ON replies.messageID = messages.id"); 

[result_id] => mysqli_result Object
    (
        [current_field] => 0
        [field_count] => 9
        [lengths] => 
        [num_rows] => 1
        [type] => 0
    )

[result_array] => Array
    (
    )

[result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[custom_result_object] => Array
    (
    )

[current_row] => 0
[num_rows] => 
[row_data] =>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain the actual issue is that you're facing?

Comment: it's hard to understand without elaborating your case by sample input and the desired output.

Comment: @Jonnix Not getting any data back from the left join. I have data in messages but nothing in replies and I hope to get data from messages if nothing in replies.

Comment: Okay, next, how do the dumps relate to the code? What variables were dumped and where? `[num_rows] => 1` implies there is at least one row available?

Comment: @Jonnix this came from the rows... `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [timestamp] => 
            [userID] => 
            [message] => 
            [messageID] => 
        )

)` the data comes from the replies table and nothing from messages

Comment: @ThomasC Meaning what? What variable did you dump out? Have you actually fetched the data after querying?

Comment: @Jonnix I dumped out row_array() to get that data

Answer (score 0):

you can try use `RIGHT JOIN`.

Or

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT       messages.*, replies.*
                        FROM        replies 
                        LEFT JOIN  messages  ON replies.messageID = messages.id");
```